# ACF variable not adding to array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have the below code. Everything is working fine, and $thumb when echoed is outputting the correct value (a URL), however when I am adding it to this array category_image is just a blank value.

```
function th_get_places_data(){
    $maps_data = th_get_places();

    if(!$maps_data) return;

    $places_array = array();
    foreach ($maps_data as $key => $id) {
        $location = get_field('location', $id);
        //print_r($location);
        //$term = wp_get_post_terms($id, 'place_category');
        $term = get_terms(
            'place_category',
            array(
                'hide_empty' => false
            )
           );
        //print_r($term);
        $lat = $lng = '';
        if($location !== '' && !empty($term) ){
            $lat = $location['lat'];
            $lng = $location['lng'];

        $category_img_slug = 'place_category_' . $term[0]->term_id;
        $thumb = the_field('category_thumbnail', $category_img_slug );
        echo $thumb;
        //Outputs https://localhost/image.png
            $places_array[$key] = array(
                'id'             => $id,
                'title'          => get_the_title($id),
                'address'        => get_field('address', $id),
                'phone'          => get_field('phone', $id),
                'url'            => get_field('url', $id),
                'lat'            => $lat,
                'lng'            => $lng,
                'category'       => $term[0]->slug,
                //category_image returns blank
                'category_image' => $thumb
                // Adding URL manually works fine
                //'category_image' => 'https://localhost/image.png'
            );
        }
    }

    return $places_array;
}
```

Can anyone let me know why this URL string isn't being added?

var_dump of array:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(9) { [“id”]=> int(248) [“title”]=> string(15) “Coastal Cookery” [“address”]=> string(41) “4553 Some Ave, Some City, BC V9A 2N9” [“phone”]=> string(14) “(555 455-5568” [“url”]=> string(0) “” [“lat”]=> float(49.8390779) [“lng”]=> float(-124.5282024) [“category”]=> string(12) “arts-culture” [“category_image”]=> NULL } [1]=> array(9) { [“id”]=> int(237) [“title”]=> string(21) “A restaurant” [“address”]=> string(41) “123 Some St, Some City, BC V2A 3A2” [“phone”]=> string(12) “250-345-6789” [“url”]=> array(3) { [“title”]=> string(7) “Contact” [“url”]=> string(44) “http://localhost/contact” [“target”]=> string(0) “” } [“lat”]=> float(49.8315734) [“lng”]=> float(-124.5197612) [“category”]=> string(12) “arts-culture” [“category_image”]=> NULL } } Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 248 [title] => A restaurant [address] => Some Ave, Some City, BC V9A 2N9 [phone] => (555) 455-5568 [url] => [lat] => 49.8390779 [lng] => -124.5282024 [category] => arts-culture [category_image] => ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 237 [title] => Some Restaurant [address] => Some St, Come City, BC V2A 3A2 [phone] => 250-345-6789 [url] => Array ( [title] => Contact [url] => http://localhost/contact/ [target] => ) [lat] => 49.8315734 [lng] => -124.5197612 [category] => arts-culture [category_image] => ) )
```

Comment: @Mech What do you mean?

Comment: Not seeing anything. Trusting you when you say `$thumb` is a string. What does a `var_dump` of the returned array look like? The value is empty, or is `category_image` key not even present? How are you determining this?

Comment: Use `var_dump`. Since we can't see all the code for all we know the value returned by `the_field` is an object and when you *echo* it we see the `__toString` representation of said object.

Comment: Added var dump. I changed some of the restaurant and address details after, so don't worry if they aren't identical.

Comment: Ok, `NULL` isn't exactly an empty value. Change `echo $thumb;` to `var_dump` also. Want to compare that with what we see in your array. Focus here is really understanding what is returned by call to  `the_field()`.

Comment: var_dump just gives me a NULL for $thumb. I am using ACF for the get_field function.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: Stupid mistake on my end, sorry. Just needed to change the function to get_field instead of the_field. Fixed now.

Comment: No worries. Learn from it. The `var_dump` is a good first sanity check. A decent IDE can also help a lot with typos like this. It would show (visual cue) as an undefined method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are developing a WordPress website with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. If so, the following code is wrong:

```
$thumb = the_field('category_thumbnail', $category_img_slug );
```

Because, according to the [ACF document](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/), calling the `the_field()` function is the same as `echo get_field()`. So you must use the `get_field()` function instead:

```
$thumb = get_field('category_thumbnail', $category_img_slug );
```